# Disable EF Core's convention of including all properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

EF Core (like EF before it) automatically adds [properties with a get/set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/included-properties#conventions) to the model.

I use the Fluent API, and I need to remember to ignore them, and it gets tedious - I always get runtime errors because I keep forgetting.

I want EF to include only those properties I've configured.

How do I disable this convention?

Comment: what 'runtime errors'?

Comment: @LeiYang The property is/isn't configured and I do/don't use it without knowing that EF thinks of it differently. However that's not the real problem - even if I wasn't getting errors, I'd still want to disable this convention.

Comment: how about create some code snippets? since what you want is actually automating repetitive work.

Comment: @LeiYang I want to remove the actual problem, which is the convention. If it's possible, that is. I can't find a way to do it, but there is a lot in EF Core which hasn't been documented yet, so maybe there is a way, and I don't know about it.

Comment: EF Core is [open source](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework)

Comment: @LeiYang I know, so what?

Comment: so you say 'not documented' is not a problem

Comment: @LeiYang I want to rely on official methods, not dig into source. Some stuff isn't documented in teh official site, but on the various blogs, etc., of the EF authors. I want to know what's possible.

Answer (score 6):

Conventions that will be applied are collected by EF Core before DbContext.OnModelCreating is called in a ConventionSet object, and the ModelBuilber passed to OnModelCreating will already contain entities and properties discovered by the conventions.

However, conventions do not just represent a ‘do it once in the beginning and forget them’ rule to determine the model, they are constantly applied whenever you change the model with the Fluent API. If you manually add an entity, the conventions for discovering properties etc. are executed at this time, and the model is always kept up to date.

The ConventionSet object defines a list of ‘events’, like ‘entity type added’, and for each event the conventions that are to be executed.

One of these events is ‘ModelInitialized’ which is run right in the beginning to initially identify entities via a DbSetFindingConvention. Every entity type found by this convention however will trigger the 'event' EntyTypeAddedConventions which will then identify the properties etc. on the entities. If you just suppress DbSetFindingConvention you will still get the properties automatically once you add an entity type to the model manually.

In order to suppress property generation you would also need to remove PropertyDiscoveryConvention from EntyTypeAddedConventions.

Removing all conventions is probably not a good idea, because you would need to do EVERYTHING manually then which is tedious work. But if you have a good understand of what automatisms you would like to get ride of and which convention does what, you can remove a few of them selectively.

To suppress conventions you can exchange the – database provider specific !!! – ConventionSetBuilder service implementation.

```
public class CustomSqlServerConventionSetBuilder : SqlServerConventionSetBuilder {

    //See also notes in CustomRuntimeConventionSetBuilder


    public CustomSqlServerConventionSetBuilder([NotNullAttribute] ProviderConventionSetBuilderDependencies dependencies, [NotNullAttribute] RelationalConventionSetBuilderDependencies relationalDependencies, [NotNullAttribute] ISqlGenerationHelper sqlGenerationHelper)
    : base(dependencies, relationalDependencies, sqlGenerationHelper) {
    }

    public override ConventionSet CreateConventionSet() {
        ConventionSet cs =  base.CreateConventionSet();
        //Do not find entity types automatically
        DbSetFindingConvention dbSetFindingConvention = cs.ModelInitializedConventions.OfType<DbSetFindingConvention>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (dbSetFindingConvention != null) {
            cs.ModelInitializedConventions.Remove(dbSetFindingConvention);
        }
        //Do not find properties automatically
        PropertyDiscoveryConvention propertyDiscoveryConvention = cs.EntityTypeAddedConventions.OfType<PropertyDiscoveryConvention>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (propertyDiscoveryConvention != null) {
            cs.EntityTypeAddedConventions.Remove(propertyDiscoveryConvention);
        }
        propertyDiscoveryConvention = cs.EntityTypeBaseTypeChangedConventions.OfType<PropertyDiscoveryConvention>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (propertyDiscoveryConvention != null) {
            cs.EntityTypeBaseTypeChangedConventions.Remove(propertyDiscoveryConvention);
        }

        return cs;
    }

}
```

Replace the default implementation of the DI service in your DbContext class (for example):

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {  
 optionsBuilder.ReplaceService<Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Infrastructure.IProviderConventionSetBuilder, TechnicalUtilities.CustomSqlServerConventionSetBuilder>();
    
    }
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to avoid making this override database provider specific you could also subclass RuntimeConventionSetBuilder, override the CreateConventionSet method,  and register it for the service IConventionSetBuilder. But that interface is more likely to change in the future.

The implementation of the Conventions can be found here:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Metadata/Conventions/
The documentation can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.conventions?view=efcore-5.0

You should check which 'events' a specific convention implements, if the convention shall be suppressed, it typically should be removed from every 'event'.

This is valid for EF Core 5.0, in prior versions probably it is different. You might also have a look at https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/5737#issuecomment-225724598